# Getting warning on uploading APK file on Samsung App Store

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am uploading a Free 'Educational' app on Samsung App store. I have filled all the required data and uploaded signed 'Apk' file but i am getting Warning, which is as follows:

**"You have not yet set the information for the country or countries where you want to distribute your applications. In particular cases, sale of the applications may be restricted .... "**

I don't know what is wrong, I have check whole page but there is no such option for selecting countries etc. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Samsung store was not loading countries list, after 2 to 3 tries countries list was loaded  and problem solved but I lost 2 to 3 hours on this heck